# Why is one question about the Catalan referendum open and upvoted, and the other one is closed as off topic and downvoted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, down-votes

[What are plausible possible outcomes after the Catalan referendum?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24535/what-are-plausible-possible-outcomes-after-the-catalan-referendum)

This thread was put on hold with -5 votes and deemed "off topic".

[If the independence vote in Catalunya is successful. What are the possible outcomes?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21847/if-the-independence-vote-in-catalunya-is-successful-what-are-the-possible-outco)

This thread, **which asks the exact same question**, has currently a bunch of answers, healthy discussion, and 10 upvotes.

Please explain this incosistency?

Comment: I just reopened the first and then closed it as a duplicate of the second, because the second was posted two months earlier.

Comment: I removed the account that posted this since it was a sockpuppet of a known troll trying to evade suspension (and went haywire in comments). Still, even if poorly phrased originally, this is a decent Meta question. The initial reception of the latter question was a bit problematic.

Comment: This is just because when people see a question starts being downvoted, they like voting it further down, no matter how good/bad the question is. The second reason is that the second question (first in your post) started off much worse than it currently is, and was edited to become better.

Answer (score 5):

First one is easily explained by the fact that the original down-voting and closing pertained to ***original***, bad, version of that question, whose title wasn't the objective-ish answerable "plausible outcomes" but instead a wholly subjective speculative **"[What is going to happen after the Catalan referendum](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/24535/revisions)?"**

Please note that once a user fixed the question up it went from 5 downvotes to 2 upvotes+2 downvotes, probably because 2 people moved on and didn't notice the fix.

The second one has 10 upvotes (instead of 2) and tons of answers because it was a lucky beneficiary of tons of views (306 views) and likely ended up on Hot network Questions list.